# How can I map through an object in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a response like this:

[image]

I want to display the name of each object inside this HTML:

```
{subjects.map((item, i) => (
  <li className="travelcompany-input" key={i}>
    <span className="input-label">{ item.name }</span>
  </li>
))}
```

But it throws an error of `subjects.map is not a function`.

First, I have to define the keys of the objects where it creates an array of keys, where I want to loop through and show the `subject.names`.

What I also tried is this:

```
{Object.keys(subjects).map((item, i) => (
  <li className="travelcompany-input" key={i}>
    <span className="input-label">key: {i} Name: {subjects[i]}</span>
  </li>
))}
```

Comment: Thnx for saying you know the answer?

Comment: A word of **caution** here.The order of keys is not gauranteed in an object and if something else modifies the object it may return the keys in a different order.This may result in content shifting around.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

When calling `Object.keys` it returns a array of the object's keys.

`Object.keys({ test: '', test2: ''}) // ['test', 'test2']`

When you call `Array#map` the function you pass will give you 2 arguments;

1. the item in the array,
2. the index of the item.

When you want to get the data, you need to use `item` (or in the example below `keyName`) instead of `i`

```
{Object.keys(subjects).map((keyName, i) => (
    <li className="travelcompany-input" key={i}>
        <span className="input-label">key: {i} Name: {subjects[keyName]}</span>
    </li>
))}
```

Comment: and to map through another field array

Comment: Is there a reason not to use Object.values instead?

Comment: @MadOgre not really - this was based on the OP's current solution. They used `Object.keys`

Answer (score 27):

You get this error because your variable `subjects` is an `Object` not `Array`, you can use `map()` only for Array.

In case of mapping object you can do this:

```
{ 
    Object.keys(subjects).map((item, i) => (
        <li className="travelcompany-input" key={i}>
            <span className="input-label">{ subjects[item].name }</span>
        </li>
    ))
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Use `Object.entries()` function.

`Object.entries(object)` return:

```
[
    [key, value],
    [key, value],
    ...
]
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

```
{Object.entries(subjects).map(([key, subject], i) => (
    <li className="travelcompany-input" key={i}>
        <span className="input-label">key: {i} Name: {subject.name}</span>
    </li>
))}
```

Answer (score 12):

I use the below `Object.entries` to easily output the key and the value:

```
{Object.entries(someObject).map(([key, val], i) => (
    <p key={i}>
        {key}: {val}
    </p>
))}
```

Answer (score 9):

Map over the keys of the object using `Object.keys()`:

```
{Object.keys(yourObject).map(function(key) {
  return <div>Key: {key}, Value: {yourObject[key]}</div>;
})}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you get an error when you try to map through the object keys, or does it throw something else.

Also note when you want to map through the keys you make sure to refer to the object keys correctly. Just like this:

```
{ Object.keys(subjects).map((item, i) => (
   <li className="travelcompany-input" key={i}>
     <span className="input-label">key: {i} Name: {subjects[item]}</span>
    </li>
))}
```

You need to use `{subjects[item]}` instead of `{subjects[i]}` because it refers to the keys of the object. If you look for subjects[i] you will get undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why Aleksey Potapov marked the answer for deletion but it did solve my problem.
Using Object.keys(subjects).map gave me an array of strings containing the name of each object, while Object.entries(subjects).map gave me an array with all data inside witch it's what I wanted being able to do this:

```
const dataInfected = Object.entries(dataDay).map((day, i) => {
    console.log(day[1].confirmed);
});
```

I hope it helps the owner of the post or someone else passing by.

Comment: Instead of ```(day, i)``` you can do ```([key, val], i)``` and directly use the ```val``` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) to direct convert object to array:

```
_.toArray({0:{a:4},1:{a:6},2:{a:5}})
[{a:4},{a:6},{a:5}]
```

In your case:

```
_.toArray(subjects).map((subject, i) => (
    <li className="travelcompany-input" key={i}>
        <span className="input-label">Name: {subject[name]}</span>
    </li>
))}
```