# React | Items.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, downshift

I am using Downshift, in order to create a dropdown that displays some menu options. I created a reusable React component with downshift, but now I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: items.map is not a function
    at IconDropdown.react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.createElement.react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.createElement (index.jsx:29)
```

Here is the code this error refers to:

```
{isOpen ? (
              <div className="dropdown-menu">
                {items.map(item => ( // Specifically this map
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    {...getItemProps({ item })}
                    key={item}
                    className="dropdown-item"
                  >
                    <Icon icon={item.icon} /> {item.name}
                  </button>
                ))}
              </div>
            ) : null}
```

And I am using it in my main Screen Component like this:

```
 items = {
  editUser: {
    name: 'Edit Info',
    icon: 'pencil-square-o'
  },
  changePassword: {
    name: 'Change Password',
    icon: 'lock'
  },
  deleteUsed: {
    name: 'Delete user',
    icon: 'trash-o'
  }
};

render() {
 return (
  <IconDropdown items={this.items} />
)}
```

**Expected behavior:**
Render a list of menu items, with their corresponding icons.

**Current Behavior:**
I get the above error. I am not sure what is wrong with this code. On my eyes this is correct.

I can post the entire component if you want, just let me know.

**UPDATE, The entire Dropdown Component:**

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import Downshift from 'downshift';

import Icon from 'lenses/common/components/Icon';

import './styles.scss';

const IconDropdown = ({ items, ...otherProps }) => (
  <Fragment>
    <Downshift {...otherProps}>
      {({ getItemProps, isOpen, toggleMenu }) => (
        <div>
          <div className="btn-group">
            <button
              id="my-select"
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split"
              onClick={toggleMenu}
              data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              aria-expanded={isOpen}
            >
              <span className="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            {isOpen ? (
              <div className="dropdown-menu">
                {items.map(item => (
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    {...getItemProps({ item })}
                    key={item}
                    className="dropdown-item"
                  >
                    <Icon icon={item.icon} /> {item.name}
                  </button>
                ))}
              </div>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </Downshift>
  </Fragment>
);

IconDropdown.propTypes = {
  items: PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    icon: PropTypes.string
  })
};

export default IconDropdown;
```

Comment: From a guess I'd have to say that maybe you mean `props.items.map`, but I can't know for sure without seeing the component.

Comment: Updated the descriptions with the component..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.map` doesn't exist from an object `{}`, it only exists from an array `[]`. You can:

- Change your object to an array
- Use `Object.keys(items).map(...)`
- Use [`lodash.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put `Object.keys(objectname)` before you array map.

Map function needs an array to work, with `Object.keys(objectname)`, you will transform an object `{}` to an a valid array `[]` for map.

```
Object.keys(items).map(item => ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Youre iteration on `object` this should be `array`
Just change

```
items = {
  editUser: {
    name: 'Edit Info',
    icon: 'pencil-square-o'
  },
  changePassword: {
    name: 'Change Password',
    icon: 'lock'
  },
  deleteUsed: {
    name: 'Delete user',
    icon: 'trash-o'
  }
};
```

TO

```
items = [{
    name: 'Edit Info',
    icon: 'pencil-square-o'
  },{
    name: 'Change Password',
    icon: 'lock'
  },{
    name: 'Delete user',
    icon: 'trash-o'
  }
];
```

Or you can use `items.enteries.map` to iterate over object

Answer (score 0):

`items` is not an array. Check post on how to map through object [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803828/reactjs-map-through-object)

An other solution would be to declare items as an array:

```
items = [
  {
    name: 'Edit Info',
    icon: 'pencil-square-o'
  },
  {
    name: 'Change Password',
    icon: 'lock'
  },
  {
    name: 'Delete user',
    icon: 'trash-o'
  }
];
```