# item.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, json, react-hooks

I am new to reactJS. i am expecting the json data to be fetched and displayed according to the options that are clicked. I tested with console.log and the data was being fetched correctly, however when i tried using useState setItems(json), it gives me an error of 'Uncaught TypeError: items.map is not a function'

```
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function App() {

  const [option, setOption] = useState('Posts')
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=> {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${option}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setItems(json))
  }, [option])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='menuBar'>
          <button onClick={()=> setOption('posts')}>Posts</button>
          <button onClick={()=> setOption('users')}>Users</button>
          <button onClick={() => setOption('comments')}>Comments</button>
          <h2>{option}</h2>
          {items.map(item => {
            return <pre>{JSON.stringify(item)}</pre>
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If you are using JSON data then you will need to parse it before setting it to the setItems state hook. When it is parsed you will be able to use it.

Comment: Can you provide more context? Could you share some sample data that you get from the api?

Comment: If the `fetch` resulted in something other than an array (i.e., `json` is an object or a primitive), this code will fail. Verify the data is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React | Items.map is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137072/react-items-map-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Your issue is somewhere else, as you can see this works https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-1ywllg?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: @David The OP is using the Fetch API, whose [`Response` object has a `json()` method that parses the JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json), and the OP is using it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code fail-safe and easier to debug, you should check if `items` is an array before using `map`.

```
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [option, setOption] = useState("posts");
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${option}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setItems(json));
  }, [option]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="menuBar">
          <button onClick={() => setOption("posts")}>Posts</button>
          <button onClick={() => setOption("users")}>Users</button>
          <button onClick={() => setOption("comments")}>Comments</button>
          <h2>{option}</h2>
          {Array.isArray(items) ? items.map(item => <pre>{JSON.stringify(item)}</pre>) : <pre>{JSON.stringify(items)}</pre>}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```