# Loop const elements and render values

Tags: reactjs

I have the following const:

```
const dictionaryData = {
  "Car1": "Ford",
  "Car2": "Dodge",
  "Car3": "Chevrolet",
  "Car4": "Nissan",
  "Car5": "Toyota",
  "Car6": "Honda",
};
```

What I want to do is loop through the CarN elements and render a span with the brand value. Something like this:

```
<span key="Car1">Ford</span>
```

I tried doing a **dictionaryData.map()** but this is not working (getting dictionary.map() is not a function error), I think that it's because is not an array. So my question is: how can I through that const and access to the brand values? Maybe is not possible change that const to an array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS map through Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803828/reactjs-map-through-object)

Comment: Why not use a simple array of car objects instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Object.entries() method returns an array of a given object's own
> enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs. This is the same
> as iterating with a for...in loop, except that a for...in loop
> enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well. [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
Object.entries(dictionaryData).map(([key, value]) => {
 return <span key={key}>{value}</span>
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to iterate over an array with `map()`. You could grab the object keys with [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), then use the value of the key at each iteration to grab the value from the original object.